# Convert string date long format to 12h date format

Tags: ios, swift, date

I have a function that works well if the format is in 24h but however in 12h it does not work well, I'm trying to apply this to correct it but the result of the 3 line is 'nil', some reason why this is happening?

```
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-02-01 14:55:08")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
    let stringdate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    let newDate12h = dateFormatter.date(from: stringdate)
```

this line return nil :

```
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-02-01 14:55:08")
```

[image: This problem is enabled or not 24h]

Comment: you say this line ***let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-02-01 14:55:08")***

Comment: but however in 12h it does not work well - not clear

Comment: The problem is this line
 let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-02-01 14:55:08"),

Comment: the function example is for convert string date to 12h format , when I use the function to 24h format , it works ..

Comment: it works correctly on swift playground for me, you can just force unwrap date in this line "let stringdate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)" -> "let stringdate = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)"

Comment: @Alejandro - for my  undertsand , if you using 24 hr to 12hr its works perfectly , if you used 12 hr to 12 hr is not works well correct or else

Comment: If in the configuration of the phone I have a 24-hour clock works fine, otherwise, it does not work well.

Comment: can you add the additional example with screen shot

Comment: update the screen

Answer (score 2):

I does work when add this line :

```
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier:"es_ES")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are simply missing an `a` in the format?

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: "2017-02-01 14:55:08")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"
let stringdate = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
let newDate12h = dateFormatter.date(from: stringdate)
```

works for me in Swift Playground.

Comment: I does not work , your settings time format es 12h available ? or your settings time format is 24h? See date and hour configuration in your phone and change to hour-clock 24h to false

Comment: If I change the initial time to "2017-02-01 11:55:08", I also get the correct 12 h format.  So I'm not sure where your problem is coming from.

Comment: update the screen with the problem , try with this configuration.

Comment: I have the same configuration as you (24-hour time switch set to off).  And my code above works fine on my device.

Comment: I does work when add this line : dateFormatter.locale = Locale.init(identifier:"es_ES")